# Cannot predict single instance in Keras using a loop

Tags: python, keras

I'm playing a little with deep learning and Keras has been my choice due to its simplicity.

I've built a simple multilayer perceptron model for binary classification and fitted it on input data (the same that I'm using for other ML models and which are working ok).

The Following picture displays the Model summary:

[image]

The first dense layer was defined as such:

```
model.add(Dense(18, input_dim=len(X_encoded.columns), activation = "relu", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
```

When I attempt to predict over a loop like so:

```
for vals in X_encoded.values:
    print("Survives?", model.predict([vals], batch_size=1))
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_90_input to have shape (35,) but got array with shape (1,)

These are my variable sizes:

```
print("Shape of vals:", vals.shape, "Number of Columns and First Layer Dimension:", len(X_encoded.columns))
```

Result:

> Shape of vals: (35,) Number of Columns and First Layer Dimension: 35

As you can see, these match in size which is the expected input.

What is going on? When I pass the entire dataframe "predict" it works correctly, but not when I pass a single value...

Comment: try removing `batch_size` argument and running it again

Comment: Batch_size does not intervene with the result.

Comment: can you printout and post the shape of `vals`?

Comment: try running `model.predict(vals)`

Comment: This is from the pring: Shape of vals: (35,)
And using model.predict(vals) does no charm.

Comment: con you post the value of `len(X_encoded.columns)`?

Comment: This is what I get: Number of Columns: 35

Comment: can you printout and post `vals` at any step?

Comment: The printing is from inside the loop, and yes, I could print all hundreds of lines, but don't think would make the problem more explicit...

Comment: the opposite actually, it could help allot

Comment: try to run: `model.predict(np.zeros((1, 35)))`

Comment: model.predict(np.zeros((1, 35))) works.

Comment: your model expects an input of an array consisting of arrays with 35 numbers in each(shape == (batch, 35)), your `vals` has a different shape, i recommend you check if your data fits your model's input, oh and also `np.zeros((1, 35))` looks like this: `array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0.]])` here 1 is `batch` and 35 is your model's input shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array, not a list. You only use a list for multiple input tensors.

```
model.predict(np.array([vals]), batch_size=1)
```

But why not:

```
model.predict(X_encoded.values, batch_size=1)
```

Comment: np.array returns the same problem.
I don't use the complete input because I want to compare each prediction to a set of other machine learning models that are not mentioned in the question.

Comment: model.predict(np.array([vals]), batch_size=1)  Works